# SAP HANA VORA and Hana CONNECTION

Tags: hana, vora

I want to access a table which is already present in SAP HANA from the Spark-shell using SAP HANA Vora.

I created the table using this command:

```
sqlContext.sql( s"""
    CREATE TABLE ztemptest 
    USING
      com.sap.spark.hana
    OPTIONS (
      path         "ztemptest",
      host         "${HANA_HOSTNAME}",
      dbschema     "${HANA_SCHEMA}",
      user         "${HANA_USERNAME}",
      passwd       "${HANA_PASSWORD}",
      instance     "${HANA_INSTANCE}"
    )
    """.stripMargin )
```

If I execute a *show table* command it's showing the table name, however when I execute `sqlContext.sql("select * from ztemptest").show` I get the error as seen in the below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide schema name as well .

Give the code as below:

```
%vora 
CREATE TABLE TABLENAME 
USING com.sap.spark.hana
OPTIONS (
   path "HANATABLENAME",
   dbschema "SCHEMANAME",
   host "HANA SYSTEM HOST NAME",
   instance " INSTANCENUMBER",
   user "USERNAME",
   passwd "PASSWORD"
)
```

Comment: im using spark shell and executing this command vc.sql( s"""
    CREATE TABLE ztemptest1
    USING
      com.sap.spark.hana
    OPTIONS (
      path         "ztemptest1",
      host         "${HANA_HOSTNAME}",
      dbschema     "${HANA_SCHEMA}",
      user         "${HANA_USERNAME}",
      passwd       "${HANA_PASSWORD}",
      instance     "${HANA_INSTANCE}"
    )
    """.stripMargin )

Answer (score 1):

With the HANA datasource (`com.sap.spark.hana`) you can either query existing tables in HANA or create new tables in HANA. If you want to query an existing table you can either provide the column+datatype information of the HANA table or not. If you do not provide it the schema metadata is queried from HANA automatically.
The error indicates that schema information was provided (maybe in an earlier execution), the table exists in HANA, and the schema information in Vora does not match the table definition in HANA.
Could you drop the existing table definition (`show tables` is empty) and recreate it with the command that you posted (that does not provide column information).

Comment: Thanks, the error is resolved